To solve for a triangle on cartesian plane.
The problem statement is pretty simple yet I can not seem to solve the problem and therefore need help, suggestion, hints ..anything. For which I thank you in advance.
Problem : Given equation of two of the angle bisectors of a triangle
$$a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$$
$$a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$$ and a vertex $(a,b)$ not on the given bisectors, find the equations of the sides.

Hint: reflect the vertex ($A$) about each line to $A'$ and $A''$... can you say anything about the line $A'A''$?
