Vertices of a triangle given the angular bisectors
given the equations of 3 lines concurrent at a point P
$$L_1(x,y): a_1x + b_1y + c_1=0$$
$$L_2(x,y): a_2x + b_2y + c_2=0$$
$$L_3(x,y): a_3x + b_3y + c_3=0$$
if there exists 3 unique points A,B,C such that point P is the incenter of that triangle, meaning $L_1(x,y), L_2(x,y), L_3(x,y)$ are the angular bisectors of that triangle, how can i find the coordinate of the point A,B,C in terms of the given 9 variables? without rigorous work, is there a faster way to get the coordinates?
Edit 1: as the comments mentions the points might not be unique, this question was sort of a curiosity of mine, to have a unique point, consider the following
let the intersection of $L_1(x,y), L_2(x,y)$ with the x axis be A,B, such that the point C is on $L_3(x,y)$, how to find the coordinates of the point C?

Edit 2: i found the coordinates, ill mention the method below
angles of $L_1(x,y), L_2(x,y)$ to the horizontal,
$$\angle PAB = \arctan{\left({-\frac{a_1}{b_1}}\right)}$$
$$\angle ABP = \arctan{\left({-\frac{a_2}{b_2}}\right)}$$
angles of the sides must be double that value, then the gradient of the sides are
$$\tan{\left({2\arctan{\left({-\frac{a_1}{b_1}}\right)}}\right)}= -\frac{2a_1b_1}{b_1^2-a_1^2}$$
$$\tan{\left({2\arctan{\left({-\frac{a_2}{b_2}}\right)}}\right)} = -\frac{2a_2b_2}{b_2^2-a_2^2}$$
equations of the sides CA, CB
$$\frac{y}{x + \frac{c_1}{a_1}} = -\frac{2a_1b_1}{b_1^2-a_1^2}$$
$$\frac{y}{x + \frac{c_2}{a_2}} = -\frac{2a_2b_2}{b_2^2-a_2^2}$$
finally using the sides, point C can be obtained,
$$C=\left(-\frac{b_{1}c_{1}\left(b_{2}^{2}-a_{2}^{2}\right)-b_{2}c_{2}\left(b_{1}^{2}-a_{1}^{2}\right)}{b_{1}a_{1}\left(b_{2}^{2}-a_{2}^{2}\right)-b_{2}a_{2}\left(b_{1}^{2}-a_{1}^{2}\right)},2b_{2}b_{1}\frac{c_{2}a_{1}-a_{2}c_{1}}{b_{2}a_{2}\left(b_{1}^{2}-a_{1}^{2}\right)-b_{1}a_{1}\left(b_{2}^{2}-a_{2}^{2}\right)}\right)$$
so apparently you dont even need the 3rd bisector

The premise seems off - angle bisectors do not define the size of the triangle, only its form. So you can generate a triangle by picking an arbitrary point on the line as a starting vertex, but any dilatation of the triangle (at $P$) also will satisfy those bisectors.

Geometrically, writing $P$ for the point of concurrency, we have $$|PA|\cos \angle BPC=|PB|\cos\angle CPA=|PC|\cos\angle APB$$ Choosing (arbitrary) $A$ on one line, the relation determines the (unique) locations of $B$ and $C$ on the other lines. Translating this in terms of the nine given parameters is a bit of an algebraic slog.

In the analysis for which you take vertices $A$ and $B$ to be where two of the bisectors meet the $x$-axis, finding $C$ without the help of the third line means that the resulting triangle isn't determined by the three given lines. So, you haven't actually solved your original problem. Are you no longer interested in a solution to that problem? ... BTW: You can find $C$ without trig: "Simply" reflect $A$ over $PB$ to $A'$, and $B$ over $PA$ to $B'$; then $C$ is the intersection of lines $AB'$ and $A'B$. ... BTW2: There's a typo in the denominator of the $x$-coordinate of $B$ in your image.

Come to think of it, here's a specific approach to the original problem: Choose (arbitrary) $A$ on $L_1$, and let $A_2$ and $A_3$ be the reflections of $A$ in lines $L_2$ and $L_3$. Then $B$ and $C$ are the intersections of line $A_2A_3$ with those lines.

The reason you didn't need the third bisector in your method is that your method assumes that one of the sides is parallel to the $x$ axis (in fact it is on the $x$ axis in your diagram). Without that constraint there would be multiple solutions for two bisectors, not only triangles of different sizes but also different angles at the vertices.

@Blue: right on, this post came on the heels of this, I figured it was multiple accounts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4975938/to-solve-for-a-triangle-on-cartesian-plane#comment10655953_4975938

Three lines $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_3$ concurrent at point $P$ are the interior bisectors of a triangle with incenter $P$ if and only if both of the following conditions are true:

No two of the lines are perpendicular.

None of the lines lies in the acute angle between the other two lines.


Equivalently, the lines are the interior bisectors of a triangle with incenter $P$ if and only if there exist points $A'$, $B'$, and $C'$ on $L_1$, $L_2$, and $L_3$ respectively such that angles $\angle A'PB'$, $\angle A'PC'$, and $\angle B'PC'$ are all obtuse.
This follows from the fact that the sum of any two angles a non-degenerate triangle must be less than $\pi$.
The three lines are not sufficient to determine a unique triangle.
But the three lines plus one vertex -- which can be any point on any of the lines, except for the point of concurrency -- do determine a unique triangle.
The solution in that case was given in the comments.
Suppose, for example, that we choose vertex $A$ on line $L_1$.
Reflect $A$ across lines $L_2$ and $L_3$ to obtain points $A_2$ and $A_3$, respectively.
Where the extended line through $A_2$ and $A_3$ intersects $L_2$ and $L_3$,
put points $B$ and $C$ respectively.
Then the reflection of $BC$ in $L_2$ is collinear with $AB$, since $A_2$ and $B$ lie on $BC$ and $A$ and $B$ (respectively) are the reflections of $A_2$ and $B$ in $L_2$.
So $L_2$ is the interior angle bisector at $B$.
A similar argument shows that $L_3$ is the interior angle bisector at $C$.
And as the three interior angle bisectors of a triangle are concurrent and there is only one line $AP$, $L_1$ is the angle bisector at $A$.

Of course, if you are given two points of the triangle (by virtue of knowing that one side lies on the $x$-axis) the third point is determined by the angle bisectors through the two vertices on that side, as shown in the question.
I checked the calculations up through the equations of sides $AC$ and $BC$ and found no errors. I did not check the coordinates of $C$.
